# rviz in fuerte and ubuntu 12.04 with ATI graphics card is problematic

Tags: rviz, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a new install of fuerte on ubuntu 12.04 with an ATI graphics card. I know that nvidia is the preferred graphics card for using rviz, however in the past (with ubuntu 10.04 and ros-electric), other than being slow I haven't had any problems. Now rviz is practically unusable. It runs fine when it is not rendering any shapes.  However, as soon as I add 100-200 shapes, it slows to a crawl and only refreshes every 2-3 seconds (including the ros-time display in rviz).

Is there anything I can disable or compile from source, etc. that might make rviz usable again as a visualization tool for debugging? I tried running ubuntu 2D to see if it would help and even installed gnome 3 in case the unity version of ubuntu was causing problems. None of that helped. I'd be happy running ros-electric on ubuntu 12.04 but it appears that isn't supported.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34743/rviz-in-fuerte-and-ubuntu-12.04-with-ati-graphics-card-is-problematic/) by [mkillpack](https://answers.ros.org/users/157/mkillpack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-04**:
It would probably be useful to add what kind of card you're using. Also, what types of frame rates do you get with glxgears?

**Comment by [mkillpack](https://answers.ros.org/users/157/mkillpack/) on 2013-01-28**:
this was for a radeon hd 3XXX series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For what it's worth, on a virtual machine running precise, I've seen a modest improvement (5x faster with glxgears) when I went used gazebo classic instead of the default.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkillpack](https://answers.ros.org/users/157/mkillpack/) on 2012-12-13**:
that may be useful in general, but I was using ODE directly with rviz when I saw this problem.  It seemed to be a problem with rendering large numbers of markers in a markerarray

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-13**:
Ok. 7 mths is a long time to be stuck with an unusable debugging process.. but now that groovy is here I'm sure that things are going to change again. I'd suggest trying the new code.. and if the problem is still there, sharing files/information to help someone else re-create what you're observing.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-13**:
and also, to be clear, ubuntu classic was installed with `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

**Comment by [mkillpack](https://answers.ros.org/users/157/mkillpack/) on 2013-01-28**:
I recently had to reinstall some stuff and had the same problem again.  Getting rid of the proprietary ATI drivers and using the open source ones actually resolved the problem.  Maybe that can help someone else as well.